# Exclude a value inside a string in Sumo Logic

Tags: sumologic

Is there a way that allows to exclude a value inside a string? For example, if I want to get `api/12345/authorise` and I want to get all the results that have `api/....../authorise`.

I do not mean to exclude a string, but search for a substring by using `AND`.

Comment: You might fix this with a `substring` function or some regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

Per the keyword search expression Documentation
https://help.sumologic.com/Search/Get-Started-with-Search/How-to-Build-a-Search/Keyword-Search-Expressions

The keyword search expression:

```
api/*/authorise
```

will give you api/12345/authorise for example, plus any other strings that start with api/ and end with /authorise.